# 2005 F250 Turbo Diesel Starts Rough

Tags: ford, diesel, cold-start

When it starts it takes a few cranks to get going, and it overall starts pretty rough. I was told that I could turn the key almost to ignition until the humming stops x3 and then start it to stop this issue? Is this just a cold start with a diesel? Are there ways to combat this that are healthier for my truck (methods of starting it for maximum care)?

Answer (score 1):

Textbook no.1 root cause for difficult/rough starting on a diesel are failed glowplugs. I suggest you to [check](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/51/how-to-test-for-defective-glow-plugs) them as it should be an easy task and costs nothing except some time. Perhaps you want to do it before winter as starting gets more difficult in the cold. For the correct starting procedure (unsure if you have a glowplug light on your dash) I must refer you to your user manual.

Comment: I will check the glow plugs when I get home. Ys it does have a glow plug light on the dash, and it goes away almost instantly when the key is inserted. I was wondering if maybe there is an issue with the glow plugs that could cause this to not go through the full process?

Comment: If the glow plugs are weak, that key cycling trick may get them to a higher temperature to aid in starting.  It works fine and will not cause damage, but eventually the glow plugs should be replaced.  The light is only a yes/no indication that power is being applied - in most cases it has no knowledge how hot they are getting - especially if only a few of them are at issue.  My 2002 F350 7.3 has the same issue, but I've plugged in the block heater and lived with it because the glow plugs are a pain to replace.